# How to insert new layer into learned DNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to make a new network by inserting conv layer to learned DNN in tensorflow.

For example, from

```
[conv2d_a -> conv2d_b]
```

to

```
[conv2d_a -> conv2d_c(inserted) -> conv2d_b].
```

Layers other than the inserted layer use the learned weights `conv2d_a`, and the weight of the inserted conv layer is learned by relearning `conv2d_c`.

This code does not work:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  conv2d_a = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("conv2d_a")

  # get next layer of conv2d_a (= conv2d_b) 
  tmp_a_next = conv2d_a.next

  # generate new layer connecting to conv2d_a
  conv2d_c = tf.layers.conv2d(inserts=conv2d_a...)

  # change previous layer of conv2d_b from conv2d_a to conv2d_c
  tmp_a_next.prev = conv2d_c
```

Comment: After restoring network you can create 
    conv2d_c = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2d_a, matrix2d_a, ...)
and then new copy of
    conv2d_b = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2d_c, matrix2d_b, ...)
with its old matrix and other parameters. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new model (with inserted layer or other additions) and restore only the variables that are in the checkpoint (you need to initialize remaining variables yourself).

Here is a gist that does this. It treats variables that have the same name and shape (in the checkpoint and in the current graph) as the same.

https://gist.github.com/iganichev/d2d8a0b1abc6b15d4a07de83171163d4